# Queue actions in Laravel 5

Tags: php, redirect, laravel, queue, server

I'm creating an application with **Laravel 5** and I have a problem.

I would like to press a button and perform a function in my controller, lets say **doCalculations();** and I want this to execute without letting me wait.

For example:

I press the button.
The calculation takes 10 seconds.
I want to be redirected after 1 second but let the calculation finish on the server.

How it is now: I press the button, wait 10 seconds, get redirected.

**So, how can I let the function run on the server without letting me wait?**

**EDIT:** To do this I tried to use a Queue with a command like this:

Command -> doCalculation(); which has a handle function that runs the calculation. and the following is in my controller:

```
 Queue::later(900, new DoCalculation());
 return redirect('/');
```

Still, it will only redirect me after the calculation is done. Even the 900 second wait before the command doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: This will require setting up a Queue on your server, and then creating Queued Commands http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus#queued-commands

Comment: You need to setup command queue to run things in background

Comment: I've tried using a custom command and then doing Queue::push but it still lets me wait for the calculation to redirect me.